# Rails/MySQL: Group/Distinct doubles query time using LEFT JOINS / slow performance

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, performance, join

I've got a (somewhat) complex query thats returning 60K+ customer records. I've got two left outer joins that I need to use with the query to search on associated records:

```
customers = customers.
  left_outer_joins(:phones, :emails).
  select("customers.id, customers.name, ...")

if params[:sSearch].present?
  params[:sSearch] = parse_phone_number(params[:sSearch])

  customers = customers.where(
    "customers.name like :search OR
    ..
    phones.number like :search OR
    emails.email like :search",
    search: "%#{params[:sSearch]}%"
  )
end

customers = customers.
  group('customers.id').
  order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}).
  page(page).
  per(per_page)
```

(Note: This is being used in a datatables ajax call, so the sort_column, sort_direction, page, and per_page are all parameters for that.)

I've got all my indexes in line.

Here's the main issue I'm facing: If I don't use the group('customers.id'), it will return duplicate customer records due to the left outer joins. But adding the group clause seems to increase the query times by at least 2X. Using .distinct on the end of the query seems to be even a bit slower than using group.

Is there a better/faster way to not return duplicates with left outer joins without increasing query times significantly? Right now this is taking over 1000ms.

EDIT: To answer Shadow's comment below - I'm joining multiple phones/emails because I need to search on them. What I'd expect would be that if the customer record matches the search (lets say on the joined phone), that it just returns one customer - not two.

Comment: The huge problem is that your query is against the sql standards and does not make too much sense from a business logic point of view either. If you have multiple addresses/phone numbers stored for a customer, which one should your query return? Any one of them? All of them?

Comment: Like Shadow has said you SQL is wrong... read https://www.psce.com/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/... you should not use GROUP BY to remove duplicates  DISTINCT is build for that.

Comment: Not overly familiar with Ruby, but my guess is adding .distinct to the end and removing the group() statement.

Comment: @Shadow See my edit above.

Comment: @RaymondNijland My whole question is that using DISTINCT makes my query extremely slow

Comment: If it was me I'd forget about all this ruby stuff for now. Instead, I'd provide CREATE and INSERT statements (enough to be representative), together with a desired result. After that, once I had a working query, I'd provide the results of the EXPLAIN. Then we could look at optimizing indexes.

Comment: That said, LIKE is unlikely to perform as well as FULLTEXT INDEX and MATCH

Comment: If you just want to search on the address / phone numbers, but do not want to display them, then use the `exists` operator with subquery instead of a join. However, if you do want to display the address and the phone numbers, then you have to use the join. In this case you may want to use MySQL's built-in `group_concat()` function to concatenate various addresses and phone numbers into a single value. I do not know how to express these via rails. I can only provide an answer in sql.

Comment: Thanks @Shadow that really helps! I do not need to display those values so I will try that direction!

Comment: Feel free to post your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to search on the address / phone numbers, but do not want to display them, then use the exists operator with subquery instead of a join.

The code in sql would look sg like the following:

```
select *
from customers c
where c.name like '%...%'
    or exists (select 1 from emails e where e.email like '%...%' and e.customer_id=c.id) ...
```

However, if you do want to display the address and the phone numbers, then you have to use the join. In this case you may want to use MySQL's built-in group_concat() function to concatenate various addresses and phone numbers into a single value.

Other things to consider:

1. use `union` instead of a series of `or` conditions
2. try to use fulltext index and search instead of a `like` wherever possible because a `like '%...%'` filter cannot use indexes to speed up a query.

Comment: Any direction you can offer as to how to use fulltext index and search instead of a like?